# Sorting Column Values in Flutter DataTable

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart, datatable

I am having serious difficulty in sorting columns in my DataTable.

Here is my code

```
  SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: DataTable(
    sortColumnIndex: 0,
    sortAscending: true,

    columnSpacing: 5.0,
      horizontalMargin: 10,
    columns: [
      DataColumn(label: Text('Col1'),          
      DataColumn(label: Text('Col2'),numeric: false ),
      DataColumn(label: Text('Col3'),numeric: true ),
      DataColumn(label: Text('Col4'), numeric: true),
      DataColumn(label: Text('Col5'), numeric: true),
    ],
    rows: myList
        .map(
        ((element) => DataRow(
          cells: <DataCell>[
            DataCell(Text(element["Col1"]), placeholder: true,showEditIcon: false),
            DataCell(Text(element["Col2"].toString())),
            DataCell(Text(element["Col3"].toString())),
            DataCell(Text(element["Col4"].toString())),
            DataCell(Text(element["Col5"].toString())),
          ],
        )),
    ).toList(),
  ),
));
```

What more am I meant to do? Ideally, I'd like to have the sort function on whichever column the user presses on, but for now, I'd be delighted with just 1 column working being sortable.

As you can see, I have added the constraints:

```
    sortColumnIndex: 0,
    sortAscending: true,
```

But all I get is an arrow near 1st column (ColumnIndex = 0) - which really does nothing when you press it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: myList is List of map ?

Comment: Passing `sortColumnIndex` only affects indicator arrows in the header row. Data rows aren't automatically sorted. You should [sort the data manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60440525/6131611) and call `setState` then

Comment: Thanks. How can I sort the data manually? The problem I have is that myList is not from a class . It is not instantiated from a class. I.e. I cannot invoke syntax like myList.myElement etc

Answer (score 11):

You have to add an `onSort` property to the column that will be sorted, and call a sorting function.

```dart
bool sort = true; // or `false`...

DataTable(
  sortAscending: sort,
  sortColumnIndex: 0,
  columns: [
    DataColumn(
      label: Text("Col1"),
      onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
        setState(() {
          sort = !sort;
        });

        onSortColum(columnIndex, ascending);
      }),
      ...
```

And the `onSortColum` function:

```dart
onSortColum(int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
  if (columnIndex == 0) {
    if (ascending) {
      yourDataList.sort((a, b) => a['name'].compareTo(b['name']));
    } else {
      yourDataList.sort((a, b) => b['name'].compareTo(a['name']));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. The DataTable should be part of StatefulWidget
2. The StatefulWidget is needed re-render the widget whenever the sort is required on different column
3. To trigger re-render `build(BuildContext context)` method, we should add `setState(() {}` method inside the `onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {}` like below

```
            DataColumn(
              label: const Text(
                'Name',
                style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
              onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                print("columnIndex:$columnIndex");
                print("ascending:$ascending");
                setState(() {
                  sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
                  isAscending = ascending;
                });
```

4. `onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {}` will be called every time the column header is clicked.
5. DataTable should have state variable e.g. `sortColumnIndex`, so that every sorting click on different column will reset this index, and corresponding index column will get arrow Icon.

```
        child: DataTable(
          border: TableBorder.symmetric(),
          sortAscending: isAscending,
          sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
```

6. isAscending will be used to revert the arrow, if the same column pressed again.
7. Similar to sortColumnIndex state variable; we have to sort the table data manually so that new sorted values will be rendered after the click.

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  var isAscending = true;
  var sortColumnIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: DataTable(
          border: TableBorder.symmetric(),
          sortAscending: isAscending,
          sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
          columns: <DataColumn>[
            DataColumn(
              label: const Text(
                'Name',
                style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
              onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                print("columnIndex:$columnIndex");
                print("ascending:$ascending");
                setState(() {
                  sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
                  isAscending = ascending;
                });
              },
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: const Text(
                'Age',
                style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
              onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                print("columnIndex:$columnIndex");
                print("ascending:$ascending");
                setState(() {
                  sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
                  isAscending = ascending;
                });
              },
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: const Text(
                'Role',
                style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              ),
              onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                print("columnIndex:$columnIndex");
                print("ascending:$ascending");
                setState(() {
                  sortColumnIndex = columnIndex;
                  isAscending = ascending;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
          rows: const <DataRow>[
            DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text('Sarah')),
                DataCell(Text('19')),
                DataCell(Text('Student')),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text('Janine')),
                DataCell(Text('43')),
                DataCell(Text('Professor')),
              ],
            ),
            DataRow(
              cells: <DataCell>[
                DataCell(Text('William')),
                DataCell(Text('27')),
                DataCell(Text('Associate Professor')),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```